# Find number of elements under a particular class name jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is there any easy way to find number of elements under a particular class name using jquery?

Comment: Nested elements too? What about text nodes? Multiple elements with the same class name? Show an example

Comment: like input elements alone. such as textbox, checkbox, radio..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)If you want to find DOM elements in a class then you can use following::

```
$('.class').length
```

2) if you want to find DOM element with particular class then use ::

```
$('.class').find('.childrenclass').length
```

The second solution is more useful,
Because we have to do some events on element with particular class itself and not on all child elements.
Because the elements can be append() & removed in future.
Then in that case your logic can be wrong for future.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by simply getting the length.

`$('.className').length`

The above will return the number of elements with same class name.

Or

If you want to find the number of child elements inside a particular element.

`$('.className').eq(0).children().length`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)** to get the children of your element and `length` to get the total number of children:

```
var childLen = $('.elementClass').children().length;
```

If you want to find particular child elements such as your `input` elements then use:

```
var inputLen = $('.elementClass').find('input').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of elements under a particular class name using siblings.length.

Html:

```
 <ul class="tabs">
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>         
           <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Mappings</a></li>
           <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a></li>               
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a></li>  
    </ul>
```

Jquery:
$('.tabs > li').siblings().length

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/35Axf/1/